Missing required argument $name of SaaSExportLogger getting this while running magento command(2.4.7-p2)
Missing required argument $name of SaaSExportLogger getting this while running magento command(2.4.7-p2)
try to add name in di.xml but getting same issue facing. Similar issue faced for the data exporter module
Missing required argument $name of CommerceDataExportLogger.
can someone help on this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
